# There is a way to know and check "who make"/"where come from" a NET/HTTP request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, web-applications, request

There is a way to know and check "who make"/"where come from" a NET/HTTP request?

P.S.: I am using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You a probably looking for **`request.remote_ip`** in your controller.

You can find it in the Ruby on Rails [api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-remote_ip), specifically:

> Determines originating IP address.
>   REMOTE_ADDR is the standard but will
>   fail if the user is behind a proxy.
>   HTTP_CLIENT_IP and/or
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR are set by
>   proxies so check for these if
>   REMOTE_ADDR is a proxy.
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR may be a comma-
>   delimited list in the case of multiple
>   chained proxies; the last address
>   which is not trusted is the
>   originating IP.

Comment: I need to check if a request comes from a my subdomain. What for this?

Comment: Well, technically the request does not come from your sub-domain (server). Your sub-domain serves a page to the user (client). The user then sends the request back to your sub-domain.

Comment: And what if I need to check if a request comes from a specific domain (www.example.com)?